# Find the DOM location of a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that in Jquery you can get the event.id if I had triggered an event (click, etc) but how would I get the DOM location of a simple function call

Ex :

```
<pre id="container2">...
  <script>
  FunctionCall();
  </script>
</pre>
```

I would like to get the "container2" value from inside my FunctionCall

Comment: var container2 = document.getElementById('container2'); ?

Comment: or am i missing something?

Comment: I need to get the location from within the FunctionCall without knowing it in advance...

Comment: Simply to be able to add element to a page at specific places (where this function is been called).

Comment: Well can't you pass it as an argument to FunctionCall() ?

Comment: I would like this code to be really easy to use for the users so Id like not to pass it as an argument...

Comment: I think you want to use `document.write`, you can read some [pros and cons about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/417685). (If after reading there you still want to use it then I can post this as an answer)

Comment: question is too vague... post more explicit details about what you are trying to do with more real world code example

Comment: @charlietfl - this question is not vague at all.  He wants a called sub-routine to know where the call was made.  This must exist because the browser's debugger can show the line number

Comment: @Hogan a lot depends on how the method is constructed and how it is used

Comment: There must be a way to find out the line number of a prior function call in the stack since the debugger can show it.

Comment: You should never need to know the position of an inline script. You need to change your design.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Not true, I can think of a use case.  The simple one, a logging framework for a system where you won't have access to the client's machine.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot How would you do it. The goal is kinda simple : add a specific text where ever FunctionCall is. This text might change depending on the position where the call FunctionCall is made.

Comment: @Hogan, I'm struggling with that explanation.

Comment: Something inserts the script with the function call. Arrange for that something to insert whatever you really want there instead. If it's an issue at all, then it's a server-side issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the script does not know where it was launched from so there is no generic way to do what you were asking.  You will have to either find a container div that you know in advance or insert your own known object that you can then find.

In your specific example, you could do this:

```
<pre id="container2">...
  <script>
  var fCntr = fCntr || 1;
  document.write('<div id="FunctionCallLocation' + fCntr + '"></div>');
  FunctionCall(fCntr++);
  </script>
</pre>
```

Then, from within the script, you can find the DOM element with the id that was passed to it.

Or, you could put the `document.write()` into the function itself so it marks its own location:

```
var fCntr = 1;
function FunctionCall() {
    var myLoc = "FunctionCallLocation" + fCntr++;
    document.write('<div id="' + myLoc + '"></div>');
    var myLoc = document.getElementById(myLoc);
}
```

This exact code would only work if FunctionCall was only called at page load time so the `document.write()` would work as desired.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try add an id or class to the script element. So something like this:

```
<pre id='container2'>
    <script id='location'>
        (function FunctionCall() {
            var container2 = document.getElementById('location').parentNode;
            container2.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        }())
    </script>
</pre>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if I have multiple <script id=...> it will always return the first id=location that it will find in the DOM. I need to know where the call is coming from exactly...